Reducibility of 0-1 polynomials concentrated in shifted prime degrees
Denote by $p_n$ the $n$-th prime integer, so $p_1=2,p_2=3,\dots$.
Given a positive integer $m>0$, define $$f_m(x):=\sum_{n=1}^mx^{p_n-2}\in\mathbb Z[x]$$
as a polynomial with only prime-shifted-by-2 terms. I'm wondering if $f_m$ is irreducible over $\mathbb Q$ for any $m>5$?
And a computer check reveals that for $1\le m\le 200$, only $f_5$ is reducible.
I tried Cohn's irreducibility criterion which asserts that finding a prime $f_m(k)$ for some $k$ would suffice. But it seems there's no particular pattern for such $k$.

Here's the decomposition of $f_5$:
$$x^9 + x^5 + x^3 + x + 1=(x^{2}-x+1) (x^{7}+x^{6}-x^{4}+x^{2}+2 x+1)$$
Here is $f_{210}$ which is irreducible:
$$x^{1289}+x^{1287}+x^{1281}+x^{1277}+x^{1275}+x^{1257}+x^{1247}+x^{1235}+x^{1229}+x^{1227}+x^{1221}+x^{1215}+x^{1211}+x^{1199}+x^{1191}+x^{1185}+x^{1179}+x^{1169}+x^{1161}+x^{1151}+x^{1149}+x^{1127}+x^{1121}+x^{1115}+x^{1107}+x^{1101}+x^{1095}+x^{1091}+x^{1089}+x^{1085}+x^{1067}+x^{1061}+x^{1059}+x^{1049}+x^{1047}+x^{1037}+x^{1031}+x^{1029}+x^{1019}+x^{1017}+x^{1011}+x^{1007}+x^{995}+x^{989}+x^{981}+x^{975}+x^{969}+x^{965}+x^{951}+x^{945}+x^{939}+x^{935}+x^{927}+x^{917}+x^{909}+x^{905}+x^{885}+x^{881}+x^{879}+x^{875}+x^{861}+x^{857}+x^{855}+x^{851}+x^{837}+x^{827}+x^{825}+x^{821}+x^{819}+x^{809}+x^{807}+x^{795}+x^{785}+x^{771}+x^{767}+x^{759}+x^{755}+x^{749}+x^{741}+x^{737}+x^{731}+x^{725}+x^{717}+x^{707}+x^{699}+x^{689}+x^{681}+x^{675}+x^{671}+x^{659}+x^{657}+x^{651}+x^{645}+x^{641}+x^{639}+x^{629}+x^{617}+x^{615}+x^{611}+x^{605}+x^{599}+x^{597}+x^{591}+x^{585}+x^{575}+x^{569}+x^{567}+x^{561}+x^{555}+x^{545}+x^{539}+x^{521}+x^{519}+x^{507}+x^{501}+x^{497}+x^{489}+x^{485}+x^{477}+x^{465}+x^{461}+x^{459}+x^{455}+x^{447}+x^{441}+x^{437}+x^{431}+x^{429}+x^{419}+x^{417}+x^{407}+x^{399}+x^{395}+x^{387}+x^{381}+x^{377}+x^{371}+x^{365}+x^{357}+x^{351}+x^{347}+x^{345}+x^{335}+x^{329}+x^{315}+x^{311}+x^{309}+x^{305}+x^{291}+x^{281}+x^{279}+x^{275}+x^{269}+x^{267}+x^{261}+x^{255}+x^{249}+x^{239}+x^{237}+x^{231}+x^{227}+x^{225}+x^{221}+x^{209}+x^{197}+x^{195}+x^{191}+x^{189}+x^{179}+x^{177}+x^{171}+x^{165}+x^{161}+x^{155}+x^{149}+x^{147}+x^{137}+x^{135}+x^{129}+x^{125}+x^{111}+x^{107}+x^{105}+x^{101}+x^{99}+x^{95}+x^{87}+x^{81}+x^{77}+x^{71}+x^{69}+x^{65}+x^{59}+x^{57}+x^{51}+x^{45}+x^{41}+x^{39}+x^{35}+x^{29}+x^{27}+x^{21}+x^{17}+x^{15}+x^{11}+x^{9}+x^{5}+x^{3}+x+1$$
